# Как сделать цветное изображение внутри осветленного блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При активном элементе вокруг него фон должен становиться непрозрачным.
Каким образом можно убрать осветление подложки в одном месте?

```css
section.animal-img {
  height: 330px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: 25%;
  background-position-x: center;
  box-shadow: 9px 6px 13px #bbb;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

section.animal-img:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ffffff70;
}

section.animal-img .circle-btn:nth-child(1) {
  top: 6rem;
  left: 6rem;
}

section.animal-img .circle-btn span {
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: #62bd45d4;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px;
  margin: 40px 70px;
}

.circle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle-btn.active {
  background: url(http://cs.samodel96.ru/CwABAIQAPAE8_8P-ww/mkf9xDfaHnQD3a6uCDuHfw/sv/image/fe/7a/c7/306766/33/ic-5.png?1459849196) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.circle-btn span {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  background: #62bd45;
  width: 320px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.circle-btn.active span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="animal-img" style="background-image: url(http://pipcat.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/8696591-770x330.jpg);">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="directory-animal-circle">
        <div class="circle-btn active">
          <span>
                АМИЛОИДОЗ<br>
                АНЕМИЯ<br>
                АСПЕРГИЛЛЁЗ<br>
                ВИРУС КОШАЧЬЕЙ ЛЕЙКЕМИИ<br>
                ГЕМОПЛАЗМОЗ<br>
                ГИСТОПЛАЗМОЗ<br>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: а конкретно на каком элементе надо сделать фон ?

Comment: Вокруг circle-btn

Comment: там же и так жёлтая оболочка ...

Comment: Да, но вокруг отсутствует полупрозрачная подложка основной картинки, на скрине выделено рамкой

Comment: Да, при клике добавляется active, с остальных снимается.

Comment: @Дмитрий, это можно реализовать на `SVG`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Желательно смотреть на полном экране

Для такой задачи нужно использовать `mask`. Через `JS` добавляем круг и помещаем его в `mask`, который и делает часть поля видимым:

```js
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var mask = document.getElementById("btn-mask");
var circleMask = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "circle");
var circleButton = document.getElementById("circle-button");
var toMinus = document.getElementById("toMinus");
var textBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];

circleMask.style.transition = "0.3s";
textBlock.style.transition = "0.3s";
circleMask.setAttributeNS(null, "r", "0");
circleMask.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", "550");
circleMask.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", "250");
circleMask.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "white");
mask.appendChild(circleMask);

circleButton.onclick = function() {
  circleMask.classList.toggle("circle-mask-opacity");
  toMinus.classList.toggle("line-opacity");
  textBlock.classList.toggle("remove-text-opacity");
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
}

#circle-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.line-opacity {
  opacity: 0;
}

.circle-mask-opacity {
  r: 40
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 30vw;
  font-size: 1.5vmax;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #62bd45;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 7px;
  user-select: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.remove-text-opacity {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .text {
    top: 10%;
    left: 5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 700">
  <defs>
    <mask id="btn-mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.6)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://pipcat.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/8696591-770x330.jpg" width="100%" mask="url(#btn-mask)"/>
  <circle fill="#62bd45" r="20" cx="550" cy="250" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" id="circle-button"/>
  <line x1="540" y1="250" x2="560" y2="250" stroke="white"stroke-width="2" pointer-events="none"/>
  <line x1="550" y1="240" x2="550" y2="260" stroke="white"stroke-width="2" pointer-events="none" id="toMinus"/>
</svg>
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, nisi fugit iusto eaque aut minima molestiae
</div>
```